# why is awk adding extra separators when printing line with FPAT

Tags: csv, awk, replace, redhat, quotes

i have written a simple script that should parse csv fields with commas that are not surrounded by quotes. however, when using fpat, i notice that the print is adding an extra comma, whenever a variable is being modified, anyone knows why?

script :

```
gawk 'BEGIN { 
    FPAT = "([^, ]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
  }
  {
    $1 = "abc"
    print
  }' file.txt
```

content of file.txt

```
blabla,xxx,yyy,zzz
ggg,xxx,yyy,zzz
"aaaa, aaa",xxx,zzz,yyy
```

the above works fine on my mac running gnu awk 4.1.0 (zshell) printing below

```
abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
abc,xxx,zzz,yyy
```

however, when i run it on a RH box 7.8, with gnu 4.0.2 (bash), it prints below

```
abc,,xxx,yyy,zzz
abc,,xxx,yyy,zzz
abc,,xxx,zzz,yyy
```

**Note the extra comma

Comment: Can you try: `FPAT = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^ ,]+"`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in that older gawk, there have been a couple over the years as it's tricky code, e.g:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2011-08/msg00001.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-10/msg00041.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2020-04/msg00023.html

Get a newer gawk version, gawk is currently on 5.1.0, your version 4.0.2 is 8 years out of date. Meanwhile try adding this at the top of your script as a workaround:

```
{ oFPAT=FPAT; FPAT=""; FPAT=oFPAT }
```

as that worked to get around the 2 FPAT bugs I'm familiar with, or sometimes even just referencing `NF` works, e.g. `{nf=NF}`.

Having said that, `[^, ]*` means "no comma or blank" repeated but your input looks like you just want "no comma" which would be `[^,]*` - maybe changing to that would alternatively work around the problem?